how to locate my custom popup field next to day-area, client clicked in react-big-calendar
hello i am currently trying to clone google calendar.
In google calendar, depend on which day you clicked, event creating field, and event veiw field is moving just next to day area.
And also if the distance from client viewpoint is shorter than event view field or event creating field, they are automatically moving popup left to right where it has enough space.
i found i could get location information in react-big-calendar with onSelectSlot props.
but I faced main problem is that even i clicked same day, x,y value is different depend on the spot i click the day field.
so i want to get consistance location of day area, at least get the location x,y value from top:0 left:0. or get ref of day area, so that i can get the right place i should put my custom popuo field, or any good idea to put event pup on next to day area client clicked! thank you for your help
